# Define the right path when loading an XML file

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to retrieve a value called "DeafultInstDir" in an XML file:

*App.config*:

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="DefaultInstDir" value ="RITTNER">
<appSettings>
```

The path of the XML file is:

> C:\Users\dora\Documents\Visual Studio\2012\Projects\NSISSetupGenerator\NSISSetupGenerator

THE PROBLEM: C# is looking for it in:

> C:\Users\dora\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\NSISSetupGenerator\NSISSetupGenerator\bin\Debug

I've tried to load it like that:
*Setup_Generator.cs*:

```
public static string DefaultInstDir(){
   XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(App.config);
   string path = xdoc.Descendants("DefaultInstDir").First.Value();
   return path; //it should return string "RITTNER"
}
```

I've tried defining an absolute path like this:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(C:\Users\dora\Documents\Visual Studio\2012\Projects\NSISSetupGenerator\NSISSetupGenerator\App.config);
```

I've tried generating a path with this function

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath()
```

It won't find the file. The path variable returns null everytime. How can I tell my machine at which path look for the XML file?

Comment: This is no ordinary xml file - this is app.config - so you can simply use built-in ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultInstDir"] method.

Comment: Gives me a ConfigurationErrorsException...

Comment: So you need to give us the exception details if we're about to help you - otherwise your question is off-topic.

Comment: Sorry. It says - ConfigurationErrorsException was unhandled: The Configuration System could not be initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add reference to System.Configuration

Then:

```
using System.Configuration;

string path= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultInstDir"];
```

Edit: if you want a bit more advanced solution have a look at defining sections and elements classes and map them to .config file.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx

Comment: Now i am getting a ConfigurationErrorsException. It says the configuration system could not be initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. The following code...

```
     using System.Configuration;
     string path= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultInstDir"];
```

... was throwing me an exception because my XML element...

```
    <appSettings>
    <add key="DefaultInstDir" value ="RITTNER">
    <appSettings>
```

...was defined before this XML element:

```
    <configSections>...</configsections>
```

configSections must be the very first element in an App.config file.